# Confusion with Button Click Display Counter or Accumulator

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on coding an application that tracks the number of times the button on the application is clicked and displays the current number in a label.  My code is below but I'm having some trouble getting the button click to count, it just displays "1" every time the button is clicked. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim intClick As Integer
    Dim intSum As Integer

    intClick = intClick + 1
    intSum = intSum + intClick

    lblOutput.Text = intSum.ToString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you redefine your variable inside a button sub, it gets initialized as a new variable every time, hence it's always 0 to start with. So use a global variable outside the sub to do the counting.

Comment: You need to read something about variable scopes and visibility. In general every variable you define inside a sub is only seen inside it. If you need a global variable, you need to define them in the main program, if you want them to be accessible inside functions/events/subs. Even if you would be using a global variable, you would be essentially initializing (=creating) it again every time a button is clicked. So only initialize variables once unless you need to "clear" them before starting.

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx as you really need this basic information, no matter the language you are using.